# last row value returns blank with only one data row

Tags: excel, row, cell, vba

HI I have copied some code. It works fine as long there are more than two rows in each column. If there is only only one row it returns the value " "
'and not the first and only value in that column. Have can I get it to work?

```
Sub ListCombinations()
```

Dim col As New Collection
Dim c As Range, sht As Worksheet, res
Dim i As Long, arr, numCols As Long
Dim numCol As Integer
Dim Col_Cnt As Integer
Dim Rows_Cnt As Integer
    Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet5")
    Col_Cnt = sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count 'add
    Rows_Cnt = sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count ' add

```
For Each c In sht.Range("A1:B1").Cells
    col.add Application.Transpose(sht.Range(c, c.End(xlDown)))
    numCols = numCols + 1
    MsgBox "numCols =  " & numCols
Next c

res = Combine(col, "~~")

For i = 0 To UBound(res)
    arr = Split(res(i), "~~")
    sht.Range("H1").Offset(i, 0).Resize(1, numCols) = arr
Next i
```

End Sub

'create combinations from a collection of string arrays
Function Combine(col As Collection, SEP As String) As String()

```
Dim rv() As String
Dim pos() As Long, lengths() As Long, lbs() As Long, ubs() As Long
Dim t As Long, i As Long, n As Long, ub As Long
Dim numIn As Long, s As String, r As Long

numIn = col.Count
MsgBox numIn
ReDim pos(1 To numIn)
ReDim lbs(1 To numIn)
ReDim ubs(1 To numIn)
ReDim lengths(1 To numIn)
t = 0
For i = 1 To numIn  'calculate # of combinations, and cache bounds/lengths
    lbs(i) = LBound(col(i))
    ubs(i) = UBound(col(i))
    lengths(i) = (ubs(i) - lbs(i)) + 1
    pos(i) = lbs(i)
    t = IIf(t = 0, lengths(i), t * lengths(i))
Next i
ReDim rv(0 To t - 1) 'resize destination array

For n = 0 To (t - 1)
    s = ""
    For i = 1 To numIn
        s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, SEP, "") & col(i)(pos(i)) 'build the string
    Next i
    rv(n) = s

    For i = numIn To 1 Step -1
        If pos(i) <> ubs(i) Then   'Not done all of this array yet...
            pos(i) = pos(i) + 1    'Increment array index
            For r = i + 1 To numIn 'Reset all the indexes
                pos(r) = lbs(r)    '   of the later arrays
            Next r
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next n

Combine = rv
```

End Function

Comment: You will need to include more code than this, and be sure to copy it from the VB Editor to ensure it's formatted correctly and an exact match to the code you're working with.  It's clear the code above was not copied from the editor.

Comment: the xldown is the problem. There is nothing Under the first line, so it returns " "